# Can't add reference to an F# PCL from a C# PCL

Tags: c#, xamarin, reference, f#, portable-class-library

1. Create C# Xamarin Forms app
2. Add C# PCL
3. Add F# PCL
4. Try to add a reference from the C# PCL to the F# PCL

-> In the reference dialog you will see: Incompatible framework Definition: 
:NETFramework=v4.5;Profile=Profile78)

[image]

Hints from other similar questions that are marked as solved do not work. E.g. adding the reference manually will fail to compile.
I don't know where to start to figure it out. Is it a compiler problem, a xamarin problem? I don't think it's the last one as it does not work with VS 2015 too.

**Update 20.10.2016**

Bugrequest and Gitrepo: https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=44976

Comment: Which PCL Profile is your C# project using?

Comment: I tried it in Visual Studio 2015 and get a different error. Seems like VS doesn't know the F# project is a PCL.

Comment: @CoderDennis Also Profile 78. I created it with the Xamarin Studio default. The strange thing is that I can add the reference from the F# PCL to the C# PCL without a problem.I tired to change the C# project to Profile 259. Same prob. In the F# project I do not see options to change the profile (in Xamarin Studio)

Comment: In VS I cannot change the Target Framework either but I noticed that the Target F# runtime was 3.1. Changed it to 4.0 but still cannot add a reference.

Comment: Trying to reference it in VS15 shows "Unable to add a reference to project pclfs. Portable Library projects can only reference other Portable Library projects and assemblies" -> Is the F# PCL not a PCL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jason Imison figured out a workaround:

1. Even if F# was installed with VS the F# tools are required https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48179
2. Then it is possible to add a reference by using the assembly (not by project) and it will compile

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't able to reproduce this in Xamarin Studio. Based on what I tried and the screenshots, I am guessing that the F# PCL is a different profile target than the C# PCL. Double-check that the Targets are exactly the same and try again.

Comment: Are you sure you tried to reference the fspcl from you cspcl? Here is the discussion with a github repro. But this repo has the ref in the wrong direction so that it works. It doesn't work the other way as I mentioned: https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/73601/f-cant-add-reference-to-an-f-pcl-from-f-forms-pcl?